# Color problem in PSTricks

Tags: pstricks

I have the following code in Pstrick but the text color is not changing. Always text color shows black. I am running this code with xelatex

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=9in,paperwidth=13.24in,margin=0in]{geometry}
  \usepackage[dvipsnames,prologue,table]{pstricks}
 \usepackage{pst-text}
\usepackage{pst-char}
\usepackage{pst-grad}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[ISBN=978-80-85955-35-4]{ean13isbn}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf,pst-text}
% begin the document and suppress page numbers
\DeclareFixedFont{\RM}{T1}{ptm}{b}{n}{2cm}

\begin{document}    
\psset{linecolor=yellow, fillstyle=gradient, gradbegin=white, gradend=blue}
\rput[lb](9,7){\pscharpath{ \RM Narayan}}
\end{document}
```

Please help me regarding this. The file is compiling and giving output but without color.

Comment: How that, without colour?

Comment: yes text is in black color. I am running the code in Xelatex

Comment: In `xelatex` I have no image! Can't you run `pdflatex` (with `auto-pst-pdf`)?

Answer (score 2):

With `\pscharpath` you can't use `xelatex`. Use always `latex->dvips->ps2pdf` or package `auto-pst-pdf` and then `pdflatex`. Or, as an alternetive, use package `pst-pdf` and run the document with `ps4pdf file.tex`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=9in,paperwidth=13.24in,margin=0in]{geometry}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,prologue,table]{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-text}
\usepackage{pst-grad}
\usepackage{pst-pdf}
% begin the document and suppress page numbers
\DeclareFixedFont{\RM}{T1}{ptm}{b}{n}{2cm}

\begin{document}    
\begin{pspicture}(17,10)
    \psset{linecolor=yellow, fillstyle=gradient, gradbegin=white, gradend=blue}
    \rput[lb](9,7){\pscharpath{ \RM Narayan}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or with package `auto-pst-pdf` instead of `pst-pdf` and then running `pdflatex --shell-escape file`